# MySQL filter checkboxlist values

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to filter multiple values which are comma seperated stored in my database. When I store my values I implode them to for example '53,57,58'. So I can explode this again to show the right values in my overview. But now the thing.

I filter them now (I use YII) using an inCondition:

```
if( count( $sector ) > 0 )
   $criteria->addInCondition( 'sector', $sector );
```

So this works when I select 1 option. If I select 2 options it only works if the selected options are in the same order like the database record. So this doesn't happen a lot ;-).

Now my question. How do I match my search value with my database record? Does anyone know how to handle this?

Thanks!

Edit:
Solution:

Works to loop thrue the array and add search condition for each selected item like this:

```
if( count( $niveau ) > 0 ){
    foreach ($niveau as $n)
        $criteria->addSearchCondition( 'niveau', $n, true, 'AND' );
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Otherwise you are on the wrong site.

Comment: Wow, funny how you can get stuck and keep thinking in the same direction... Tried different conditions, but now I wrote everything down here: I think I should loop true the selected values of my filter and add a inCondition for every selected value. I'll post the code later (if it works :p).

Comment: I think you need to use `MATCH -- AGAINST` In SELECT Query...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(count($niveau)) > 0) {
    $niveauConditions = array();
    foreach($niveau as $n) {
        $niveauConditions[] .= "CONCAT(',', `niveau`, ',') LIKE '%,{$n},%'";
    }
    $criteria->addCondition(implode(' OR ', $niveauConditions));
}
```

Also think you can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)